# Creating XSLT from specific XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT. Need help on creating XSLT from below input XML.

```
<root>
 <a>
    <b type="Test"></b>
  </a>
  <c></c>
  <d>
  </d>
  <e>
    <f>Test1</f>
    <f>Test2</f>
  </e>
  <e>
    <f>Test3</f>
    <f>Test4</f>
  </e>
  <e>
    <f>Test5</f>
  </e>

  <a>
    <b type="Rest"></b>
  </a>
  <c></c>
  <d>
  </d>
  <e>
    <f>Rest1</f>
    <f>Rest2</f>
  </e>
  <e>
    <f>Rest3</f>
    <f>Rest4</f>
  </e>
  <e>
    <f>Rest5</f>
  </e>

  <a>
    <b type="Host"></b>
  </a>
  <c></c>
  <d>
  </d>
  <e>
    <f>Hest1</f>
    <f>Hest2</f>
  </e>
  <e>
    <f>Hest3</f>
    <f>Hest4</f>
  </e>
  <e>
    <f>Hest5</f>
  </e>

  <a>
    <b type="Test"></b>
  </a>
  <c></c>
  <d>
  </d>
  <e>
    <f>Test6</f>
    <f>Test7</f>
  </e>
  <e>
    <f>Test8</f>
    <f>Test9</f>
  </e>
  <e>
    <f>Test10</f>
  </e>

  <a>
    <b type="Fest"></b>
  </a>
  <c></c>
  <d>
  </d>
  <e>
    <f>Fest1</f>
    <f>Fest2</f>
  </e>
  <e>
    <f>Fest3</f>
    <f>Fest4</f>
  </e>
  <e>
  <f>Fest5</f>
  </e>

</root>
```

The expectation is it will fetch specific type tag<a> which can occurs n numbers in xml and the below <f> child tags. child tags should be merged. Tag positions are not constant. only constant pattern is "specific type and tags below that type until the next type".

The Output will be

```
<b type="Rest"></b>
<f>Rest1</f>
<f>Rest2</f> 
<f>Rest3</f> 
<f>Rest4</f> 
<f>Rest5</f> 
<f>Fest1</f> 
<f>Fest2</f> 
<f>Fest3</f> 
<f>Fest4</f> 
<f>Fest5</f>
```

Or

```
<b type="Test"></b>
<f>Test1</f> 
<f>Test2</f> 
<f>Test3</f> 
<f>Test4</f> 
<f>Test5</f> 
<f>Test6</f> 
<f>Test7</f> 
<f>Test8</f> 
<f>Test9</f> 
<f>Test10</f>
```

It will select the specific type and display all the <f> under that type.

Comment: This seems to be a [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: I am looking for help in XSLT 1.0

Comment: I searched for grouping and tried many ways but not able to get the desired output. Please help.

Comment: Post your coding attempt if you want help here.  People like to help you learn, not write code for you on demand.

Comment: Added the XSLT I am using. Please help.

Comment: *"Please help me to understand where I did wrong..."* Apparently you did not read the link in my 1st comment. It states that the preferred solution in XSLT 1.0 is to use the Muenchian grouping method. Your XSLT is nowhere near implementing this method.

Comment: Why does the first example output contain both e.g. `<f>Rest1</f>` and e.g. `<f>Fest1</f>` following `<b type="Rest"></b>`? You never explain what your input will be to determine `specific type tag<a>` but if the `a` with child `<b type="Rest"></b>` in your input sample are used I don't see why any `<f>FestX</f>` should be output as they a preceded by the `<a<b type="Fest"></b></a>`.

Comment: Its my bad and Its fixed now. Element a with child <b type="Rest"></b> in the input sample are used. Also need to consolidate all the f tags for the specific type.

Comment: Sorry. It was deleted accidently. fixing it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy in XSLT 3 with accumulators, works that way even for streamed processing:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:param name="type" as="xs:string" select="'Rest'"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip" use-accumulators="found first-found" streamable="yes"/>

  <xsl:accumulator name="first-found" as="xs:boolean" initial-value="false()" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="a/b[@type = $type]" select="if (not($value)) then true() else false()"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="found" as="xs:boolean" initial-value="false()" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="a/b[@type = $type]" select="true()"/>
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="a/b[not(@type = $type)]" select="false()"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="*/f[accumulator-before('found')] | a/b[@type = $type][accumulator-before('first-found')]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT 3 is implemented by Saxon from Saxonica on various platforms (e.g. Java with Saxon HE or higher 10, 11, 12, .NET with Saxon HE or higher 10, .NET 6/7 with SaxonCS, Python with SaxonC 11 or 12, browser and Node.js with SaxonJS 2.5) and by Altova.

With XSLT 1.0 you can try sibling recursion but it might be easier to use a key that allows grabbing the `f` elements following the `a[b/@type = $type]` and then just process those `a` elements, output the first and for each output the `f` elements the `key` function call finds:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
  
  <xsl:param name="type">Rest</xsl:param>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="group" match="root/e/f" use="generate-id(../preceding-sibling::a[b/@type][1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root/a[b/@type = $type]"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <xsl:copy-of select="b"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('group', generate-id())"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Utnas_Earth_005, that is a rather simple XPath expression selecting `a` element for which the predicate `b/@type = $type` holds, i.e. that have a `b` child element with a `type` attribute equal to the parameter `$type`. You might want to start with a tutorial or book on XPath and XSLT, a free book is https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm, for instance, to learn about XPath and XSLT. Teaching in comments to a comment on a StackOverflow answer is rather limited.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help. You have described it pretty well. I will go through the book for sure.